# Create a "for ()" loop instead of if-else

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop

I am trying to build a simple "fill in the blank" quiz.

I managed with bulky `if else` statements **-->** 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyka88/5WQgc/5/) 

 However, with more "boxes" (10+), writing a dozen `if else` statements is obviously not the best way.

I've tried and tried to make a `for (condition) {}` **loop** out of it, but with little success. 
Any pointers / help / code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to keep the questions and answers out of JS code (outside of arrays, etc.) and in the HTML, if that's possible at all in that case.

Thank you.

```
<h2> Exercise I </h2>   
<p>Fill in with <em> you </em> or <em> thank </em> 
</p>
<p> <span style="background-color: #97F897;"> Green </span> is correct , <span style="background-color: #FF1212;"> Red </span> is incorrect</p>
<br>
<FORM name="FillIn">1. Hello, how are
    <INPUT id="Q1" type="text">?
    <br>Good,
    <INPUT id="Q2" value="" name="" type="text" />you.
    <br>
    <BR>
    <BR>
    <INPUT id='getAnswers' value="Check the answers" type="button">
</FORM>
<div class="Answers">
    <INPUT id="A1" value="you" name="" type="text" />
    <INPUT id="A2" value="thank" name="" type="text" />
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#getAnswers").click(function () {
        var useranswer1 = $('#Q1').val();
        var firstanswer1 = $('#A1').val();

        var useranswer2 = $('#Q2').val();
        var firstanswer2 = $('#A2').val();

        if (useranswer1 === firstanswer1) {

            $("#Q1").css("background-color", "#97F897");
        } else {
            $("#Q1").css("background-color", "#FF1212").val("nope");

        }

        if (useranswer2 === firstanswer2) {

            $("#Q2").css("background-color", "#97F897");
        } else {
            $("#Q2").css("background-color", "#FF1212").val("nope");

        }

    });

    //last bracket
});
```

@Edgar-- thanks, I can't make your code work. It is too complex for beginner me. 
@dc2 - thank you, but the behaviour is different and I can't change it myself :)

**@Man of Snow - thank you**, it is, as you said, really basic, but the only answer that I understand properly and it works for me **perfectly**. The simpler the better as I'm a one-man army (HTML,CSS, some jQuery, Photoshop, content creation, audio, video, etc...) for a website I'm trying to pull from the ground

Comment: Care to share the code you have?

Comment: @Alexander He has a fiddle sir. What else to do want ?

Comment: Better to put the code in the question itself.

Comment: @Ani I don't know if this question would be helpful to anyone the day `jsFiddle` stops it's service. Same for all `fiddle-only` answers. (BTW St.Ov. has implemented a fiddle-only-type-of answers and automatically prevents submissions.) Or you think differently?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You have a point. But I was pointing out that the code is available if you want to work on answering it.

Comment: @Ani all users capable of *editing* questions should preferably (if time permits) edit such questions to include the relevant code into it and notify the OP to be aware of that *need-to* - for the future

Comment: It is unclear what logic you're trying to implement with 10 questions and thus unclear what problem you're really asking for help with.

Comment: to add to jfriend00, in that case if you'll have also more check buttons you should use class for them too... but it's totally unclear how you plan to do it from the code you gave us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really *basic,* non-complex way of doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#getAnswers").click(function () {
        var useranswers = [$('#Q1'), $('#Q2')];
        var firstanswers = [$('#A1').val(), $('#A2').val()];

        for (var i = 0; i < useranswers.length; i++) {
            if (useranswers[i].val() === firstanswers[i]) {

                useranswers[i].css("background-color", "#97F897");
            } else {
                useranswers[i].css("background-color", "#FF1212").val("nope");

            }
        }

        });

    //last bracket
    });
```

Also, you really should do your research before asking a question, rarely does SO code for you.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5WQgc/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
   $("#getAnswers").click(function () {
       var n = $("[id^=Q]").filter(function(){ return /^Q\d+$/.test(this.id) }).length;
       for(var i=1; i<=n i++){
          var $q = $('#Q' + i);
          var $a =  $('#A' + i);
          if ( $q.val() == $a.val()) {
             $q.css("background-color","#97F897");
          } else {
              $q.css("background-color","#FF1212").val("nope");               
          } 
       }
   });
```

Cheers

Comment: `$("[id^=Q]").length;` might return 200, or there's something I'm missing?

Comment: I added an edition to select only the correct amount. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You could think about storing answers on each input elements with jQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) function (so answers are not visible in DOM), and then do

```
$("#getAnswers").on('click', function () {
  $('input.questions').each(function() {
    var bc = $(this).data('answer') === $(this).val() ? '#97F897' : '#FF1212';
    $(this).css('background-color', bc);
  });
});
```

(I assume you add the class 'questions' on each input you have to handle)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var answers = [
 'You',
 'thank'
];

for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; ++i) {

 var qElement = '#Q' + (i+1);
 var element = '#A' + (i+1);
 var answer = $(element).val();
 var rightAnswer = answers[i];

 if (answer === rightAnswer) {
   $(qElement).css("background-color","#97F897");
 } else {
   $(qElement).css("background-color","#FF1212").val("nope");
 }
}
```

What you are doing is looping through each answer, and dynamically picking up the elements and values as they are predictable.

You could also use arrays of questions and answers to dynamically build your questions for you, without excessive HTML, if you want to cut down on the HTML as well.